# How do I list start and endpoints of CantorMesh?

Tags: regions, mesh, fractals

How do I extract start and endpoints of each defined interval of iteration `n` of `CantorMesh[n]`? The furthest I can go is

```
In[16]:= RegionBoundary[CantorMesh[3]]
```

I'm unable to find anything in the documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
MeshCoordinates@CantorMesh[3] // Partition[#, 2] & // Map[Flatten]

(*
{{0., 0.037037}, {0.0740741, 0.111111}, {0.222222, 0.259259}, {0.296296, 0.333333}, 
 {0.666667, 0.703704}, {0.740741, 0.777778}, {0.888889, 0.925926}, {0.962963, 1.}}
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`MeshPrimitives`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshPrimitives.html).

```
MeshPrimitives[
 CantorMesh[3],
 1
]
(* {Line[{{0.}, {0.037037}}], Line[{{0.0740741}, {0.111111}}], 
 Line[{{0.222222}, {0.259259}}], Line[{{0.296296}, {0.333333}}], 
 Line[{{0.666667}, {0.703704}}], Line[{{0.740741}, {0.777778}}], 
 Line[{{0.888889}, {0.925926}}], Line[{{0.962963}, {1.}}]} *)
```

There are no guarantees about the ordering of the `MeshCoordinates`, so I would not personally rely solely on that.

Answer (score 4):

A quick, but partially undocumented way to extract the edge coordinates.

```
R = CantorMesh[3];
edges = MeshCells[R, 1, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]];
pairs = Partition[Flatten[MeshCoordinates[R][[Flatten[edges]]]], 2]
```

> {{0., 0.037037}, {0.0740741, 0.111111}, {0.222222, 
>     0.259259}, {0.296296, 0.333333}, {0.666667, 0.703704}, {0.740741, 
>     0.777778}, {0.888889, 0.925926}, {0.962963, 1.}}

As Szabolcs said, one should not rely here on the correct ordering. But you can do, e.g.,

```
{start, end} = Transpose[Sort[MinMax /@ pairs]];
```

to obtain the ordered lists `start` and `end` of all start and end points, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

```
f1 = ## & @@@ ## & @@@ MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &;

f1 @ CantorMesh[3]
```

> ```
>  {{0., 0.037037}, {0.0740741, 0.111111}, {0.222222, 0.259259},
>   {0.296296, 0.333333}, {0.666667, 0.703704}, {0.740741, 0.777778},
>   {0.888889, 0.925926}, {0.962963, 1.}}
> ```

Also

```
f2 = Map[Flatten @* First] @ MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &;
```

and

```
f3  = Cases[Normal@Show[#], Line[x_] :> First /@ x, All] &;

f1 @ CantorMesh[3] == f2 @ CantorMesh[3] == f3 @ CantorMesh[3]
```

> True